# Secondary navigation on pages

Tags: 7, navigation

I want to have navigation menu inside few pages on the left panel apart from the website's main menu on the top, and these menu items will be different for different pages. Is there a module for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://drupal.org/project/menu_block.  It allows you to slice up your menus and might do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

one way to easily create this functionality, imho, is to create multiple secondary menus

1) you can then create a block for each one configure them to show on specific pages in a sidebar

2) if you have context installed, you can incorporate a particular menu according to a path (or other definitions)

3) you can also create a secondary menu with the book module

4) multiple menu modules help you create this functionality if you read their included documentation in README.txt